# Error while trying to install drupal commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce

I am new to drupal and am trying to install drupal commerce kickstart on a digital ocean server. But it fails at install profile step with the following error,

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 404 Debugging information follows. Path: http:///install.php?profile=commerce_kickstart&welcome=done&locale=en&use_dfp=1&id=1&op=do StatusText: Not Found ResponseText: 404 Not Found 404 Not Found nginx/1.0.15

I dont know what to do.  Please help.
I can install drupal easily with no issues but installing all modules for commerce is a headache so I decided against it.

NOTE:  is my website

Comment: Increase memory size and execution time.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to your php.ini file. Search and change values for the following:

  ```
  post_max_size = 500M
  upload_max_filesize = 500M
  max_execution_time = 2000
  max_input_time = 2000
  memory_limit = 512M
  ```

and save file

- In apps config

C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9/config.inc.php (whatever your server is)

add the below code

```
     //maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
     $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
```

and save the file.

- Restart your WAMP Server.

For more details go [there](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/4530/error-installing-kickstart-ajax-http-error-occurred-failure-sort-migration-list).

Comment: @Rupesh The PHP configuration file ofcourse.